# Combining twitter typeahead with JSF inputText

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

Snippet of HTML:

```
<h:panelGrid width="100%">
  <h:outputText value="From:"></h:outputText>
  <h:inputText id="departureAirport" value="#{searchFlightsBean.departureAirport}" styleClass="input-block-level blue-highlight" placeholder="Enter departure city" required="true">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="20" />
  </h:inputText>
  <h:message for="departureAirport" styleClass="alert alert-error" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

I want to, eventually, pull data for this field via AJAX, and suggest options to the user while he/she is typing.

I have included the following in my page:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/main.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
<h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" />
```

and I have the following JS, which I'm using to test the autocompletion:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#departureAirport').typeahead([ {
    name: 'planets',
    local: [ "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" ]
  }]);
});
```

The autocompletion is *not* working. Does anyone know why, exactly?
I got the typeahead example [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me), if anyone is interested.

Comment: Just mentioning : The typeahead in use is **not** the one most people know from twitter-bootstrap, but https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js.

Comment: I didn't know there was one included in the twitter-bootstrap, to be perfectly honest.

That's the main reason why I'm doing it this way.

Comment: There were / is two different typeaheads. From bootstrap v3 (the newest) the good old typeahead is replaced with Twitters Typeahead https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7747 [confused? So am I :-) would mention it because I immediately looked for errors according to the "old" typeahead, until realizing it was Twitter Typeahead ...

Comment: Ah, I understand. 

Well, I switched to bootstrap-typeahead, I'll update my question as well. Regardless, it seems that the usage of JavaServerFaces seems to break a lot of the twitter bootstrap features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JSF and the twitter-bootstrap don't play well together. I got it working with a noraml input field.